# Power BI Gateway Connection Setting

Tags: powerbi, connection-string, gateway

When a gateway connection is added by clicking "Add to gateway", even though the database server name and database name are allowed to change on the popup UI, but after entering a new database server and saved, "Not configured correctly" error message is still shown instead of letting me to map to the new data source when coming back to gateway setting page.

[image: add a new gateway connection]

Answer (score 0):

They must match.  But if you use a Power Query parameter for "server" or "database" you can change those after you deploy the report.